# Place the prev/next buttons to the top in Boostrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, slideshow

In my application, I want to visualize the clusters of my kMeans, so I thought I could use a full-window carousel, where every slide will contain 10(0) images of the cluster. So, when the user clicks the next button, he should view the 2nd cluster, etc.. I will resize the images to be all of the same size, but the problem is that the previous and next buttons will go at the mean height of the slide, making the user having to scroll down to click them, which might be not he wants.

So how to place the prev/next buttons at the top?

I tried this:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="top: 0"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
```

but nothing happened! Like Magikarp using Splash...

I am using the basic example of the Bootstrap carousel. Any idea(s)?

---

Working ( big :/ ) example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>kMeansVision</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- My includes -->
        <link href="css/full-window-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/black.jpg" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
                    <img src="img/yellow.png" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
                    <img src="img/black.jpg" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
                    <img src="img/yellow.png" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>First Image</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=689" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Second Image</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=675" data-color="violet" alt="Third Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Third Image</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=658" data-color="lightgreen" alt="Fourth Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Fourth Image</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/2000/1250?image=638" data-color="tomato" alt="Fifth Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Fifth Image</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="top: 0"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: false
            }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

where `full-window-carousel.css` is:

```
h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #B9121B;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.p {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Not exactly a working version... can you provide a snippet/jsfiddle so we can see the actual thing works?

Comment: What is not working? I know it seems big, but it's really just the basic Boostrap Carousel example @Dekel...

Comment: There is a link there to `css/full-window-carousel.css` for example, which doesn't exists. A working example is usually something you can see :) this is only a code.

Comment: @Dekel that's the file I have posted at the end of the question!! I know, and I will try to make one..But for now, a person that knows about Boostrap should be able to get it going..

Comment: Added an example, I hope it will help with your specific code :)

Comment: Thanks @Dekel for the answer and the upvote! I was about to make a JsFiddle, and made sure to include one in my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260318/make-all-images-to-be-of-the-same-size). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of bootstrap carousel with the arrows on top of the carousel.

```css
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzc3NyI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojN2E3YTdhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+Rmlyc3Qgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzY2NiI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNmE2YTZhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+U2Vjb25kIHNsaWRlPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example .</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco larunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
        <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzU1NSI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNWE1YTVhO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+VGhpcmQgc2xpZGU8L3RleHQ+PC9zdmc+">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>One more.</h1>
            <p>aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```