# Make all images to be of the same size

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, dimensions

On my way on implemented [my idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259932/place-the-prev-next-buttons-to-the-top-in-boostrap-carousel), I am trying to put a lot (toy example: 4) images in one slide of the carousel of Bootstrap. However, I am failing big time on resizing them so that all the images have same characteristics in dimensions, regardless of their original ones.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/dxn7hwsb/9/) where I display the issue in slide 1, and here is just one of the many attempts I made:

```
img.resize{
    width:256px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

You see, I would like the images to all have the same dimensions, for visualization purposes. How to do that?

In other words, what I want is every image to be of the same `width x height` dimensions. Like we were passing them through a neural layer that would trim the dimensions to make them homogenous, like all of them were placed on the same box! The ideal thing would be to get something like what t[he search engines give you](https://www.google.com/search?q=snoopy&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS701US702&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQl8645OzOAhUUzGMKHWMvCzwQ_AUICCgB&biw=1331&bih=1307) (where the height is the same for all, and the width might differ a bit, but w.r.t. to visualization that doesn't cause any harm).

Now, the black is shorter than the yellow.

Comment: What's wrong? It works... https://jsfiddle.net/dxn7hwsb/2/ every image is resized to 256px width. Or maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: Did the updated help @NoCanDo?

Comment: Nevermind...missed the update.

Comment: @gsamaras - I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you maybe put together a sample image of what your desired output is?

Comment: @GeoffJames you posted the comment just after I made my latest update with that request.

Comment: @gsamaras - typical that I post it literally seconds later! Is something like "Masonry", similar to what you might be after?: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Wow @GeoffJames that looks cool, I will surely look this into, if you know more about using this library with Bootstrap, please let me know!

Comment: @gsamaras No problem. Masonry seems quite popular across the web, by the looks of it. Not used it myself, though. And from what I can find - it seems to work pretty well with Bootstrap. Have a look on *insert favourite search engine here* and you'll be able to find some samples/tutorials :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `max-width` and set the `.item` class's height... and `overflow: hidden`:

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/dxn7hwsb/7/)**

4 images in 1 slide: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/dxn7hwsb/12/). Be aware that with just straight images you won't be able to make them the same size. Well, unless you want them squished and squeezed to look horrible.

If you want all 4 images to *appear* to be the same size, you need additional markup, such as a div wrapping the image tags. This is how things like Google images does it.... they wrap the image tag in a div, then hide any overflow of that div.

You can't resize 4 images in that current markup to be exactly the same size in a single one of those slides. Images themselves can't be cropped or have portions hidden. It's *surrounding elements* that cause images to *appear* cropped by hiding any overflow.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the answer. However, my 1st slide has 4 images, yours has only 1.

Comment: haha we thought that was an issue, gsamaras, your own jsfiddle works perfect, remove this question

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan no, my goal is to get something like the result that Google for example gives you when you search for an image, and fit that into a slide of the carousel...So for a start, I was trying to resize the images!

Comment: can you provide such a link?

Comment: So you want to cram 4 images into one slide? You aren't making sense. Here.. 4 images in one slide: https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/dxn7hwsb/12/

Comment: Yes @Scott! But wouldn't it be possible to have the black and yellow images to have the same height and width?

Comment: Not if you want all 4 images in **one** slide.

Comment: You need a div or other elements around the images to hide any overflow. You can't resize 4 images to be *exactly* the same in one of those slides. You need more markup. images themselves can't be cropped or have portions hidden. It's surrounding elements that cause images to appear cropped.